# Can not get a PHP table to function properly. PHP Dungeon

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am working on creating a Dungeon scenario with PHP. Essentially what I am attempting to accomplish is creating a 10 x 10 table that will display a set of variables that are defined by a random number. I have been hammering away at this for quite awhile now, with no avail. Hopefully someone out there can give me a hand, and point me into the right direction.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>The Dungeon</title>
<?php
function populateRoom(){
$randomNumber = rand(1,5); 
$emptyRoom = "O";
$treasure = "$";
$monster = "M";
$trap = "^";

if($randomNumber == 1 || $randomNumber ==2){
    echo "<h1><td>$emptyRoom</td></h1>";}
elseif ($randomNumber == 3){
    echo"<h1><td>$treasure</td></h1>";}
elseif ($randomNumber == 4){
    echo"<h1><td>$monster</td></h1>";}
else{
    echo"<h1><td>$trap</td></h1>";}


return array($emptyRoom,$treasure,$monster,$trap)

?>


</head>

<body>
<h2>The Dungeon</h2>

<?php

echo "<table border=\"1\">";


for ($row=1; $row<=10; $row++){
  echo "<tr>\n";

  for ($col=1; $col<=10; $col++){

   echo "<td>.populateRoom().</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to get data from function use this `list($emptyRoom,$treasure,$monster,$trap) = populateRoom();print "$emptyRoom,$treasure,$monster,$trap";`

Comment: What do you mean no luck? What is the current output? What is the problem with it? What did you try to solve it? Be specific.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong:

in your function `populateRoom()` you are trying to display your random values as a column using `<td>` and than you are trying to return an array.

And again you are calling your function as a table column which does not make any sense.

Here is the fix:
From your function only return the values.. so that when the function is called it returns exactly one random value and display it as column:

```
function populateRoom() {
    $randomNumber = rand(1, 5);
    $emptyRoom = "O";
    $treasure = "$";
    $monster = "M";
    $trap = "^";

    // I would prefer to use switch
    if ($randomNumber == 1 || $randomNumber == 2)
        return $emptyRoom;
    elseif ($randomNumber == 3)
        return $treasure;
    elseif ($randomNumber == 4)
        return $monster;
    else
        return $trap;
}
```

than you can display this value in your table:
Note: always try to avoid writing html code in your PHP tags.. its makes the code confusing and dirty. you shoud always make the code clean for any other programmers who may be in future may work on this and it will make easier for them to read:

```
 <h2>The Dungeon</h2>

<table border="1">
    <?php for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; $row++): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php for ($col = 1; $col <= 10; $col++): ?>
                <td><?php echo populateRoom() ?></td>
            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

Output:
[image]

I believe this is what your are trying to achieve:

Note: There is definitely better and more more efficient way to this. Its good for the start.

Dins

Comment: Thank you Dins! I really appreciate it, and for all the advice!